# Error while pasting the data using Excel Vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have 17 columns in my sheet 1 and when I am copying the data in sheet 2 only 13 columns are being pasted with the specified format sheet 2.

In that 17 columns I have date and time stamp. dates below 13 columns are pasted with yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format and dates which is beyond 13th column are pasted in (if this is the date 2018-03-01 03:00:00) it is pasted as 43160.125.

[image]

and the code I have used is

```
sht1.Cells.Copy
sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

P.S: I have used NumberFormat too but it's no use.

Comment: `Copy` and `PasteSpecial` is a 2- line command. You used 1) `sht1.Cells.Copy` 2) `sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` and 3) `sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats` and it didn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (**Untested**)

```
sht1.Cells.Copy
sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked. Why only xlPasteValues cannot be used. Why do xlpasteFormats need to be used with that. I believe  xlPasteValues pastes all the values. So, date and time isn't considered as a value. Is it a format?

Comment: Sort of: Dates are held as a long - the number of days since 1/1/1900. To see them in a conventional style such as "Jan 1 1900" you need a format. Similarly hours are held as decimal fractions of 24 hours - so 12 noon = 0.5

Comment: @AnkitaRoy: Have a look at this http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm